# How to connect from ASP.NET Core 5.0 application running in a container to SQL Server on Windows Server

Tags: sql-server, docker, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-5.0

I have an ASP.NET Core web API version 5.0 application with a backend that uses Microsoft SQL Server running on Windows Server. This application has been running fine when deployed / run on IIS, but when deployed / run with docker an error appears when getting data to sql server, with an error like this "**A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the pre-login handshake. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 35 - An internal exception was caught)**".

Comment: Have you sat `SA_PASSWORD` in your docker-compose file?

Comment: When you moved from IIS (Windows) to Docker (linux) you changed from using SChannel for SSL/TLS connectivity to OpenSSL. Modern versions of OpenSSL require TLS 1.2 or 1.3 connections by default, although you can usually downgrade them to TLS 1.0 and 1.1 by editing /etc/ssl/openssl.cnf. What version(s) of TLS are offered up by your SQL Server?